# How to play softly on a digital piano?

Tags: technique, digital-piano

I find it very difficult to play really soft sounds because the keys are heavy.  I could turn the volume down, but then it wouldn't replicate how loud a grand piano sounds like. I use Thomann DP-26.

Is there any technique to use on these "heavy" keys?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense – it's one of the reasons for making keys heavy that you can _better_ play softly. Of course, the DP-26 isn't exactly a high-end instrument so maybe the velocity sensitivity just doesn't work very well.

Comment: Heavy keys do make it harder to play fast AND soft.

Comment: Well, you can get a cheap unweighted MIDI master keyboard if you prefer that... most pianists strongly prefer heavy keys though, which is the only reason digital pianos are made heavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will experience this difficulty in playing softly on *any piano,* whether it be a Steinway or any digital piano with weight sensitivity (granted, there are of course minute differences).

It just takes practice. A helpful technique I learned is to **keep your fingers flat,** such that your finger tips are making contact with the keys and not the tips of your fingers. I don't know *why* this helps, but it does in fact make playing softly easier.

Comment: I always thought that grand piano tends to have lighter keys.

Comment: Nah, digital pianos come in all shapes and sizes - the nicer ones being closest to a real grand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want loud, depress the key fast.  If you want soft, depress it slowly.  Heavy keys should be EASIER to play softly, because they offer more resistence.

Comment: Wrong.  It's not speed, it's force that imparts more energy to the string (or virtual string).

Comment: The key press throws the hammer at the string.  There's no direct contact.  Throw it fast, it hits hard.   On an electric instrument there's an even more direct correlation between key speed and volume.  There's a contact at the top of the key's travel, another at (nearly) the bottom.  Velocity is calculated by the elapsed time between the two closing.   Of course you're right in a way. Hitting the key with more force will make it move faster.  Easier to control when there's some inertia to work against.

Comment: For me it is the opposite... I have to press with greater strenght because of their weight to produce a sound, so it is hard for me to do it quietly.

Comment: Really?  You can depress the key fast, but you can't depress it slowly?  I think you're inventing problems!

Comment: Laurence, you are making absolutely no sense. He's not talking about depressing the keys, he's talking about "pressing" the keys down. Releasing the piano key has nothing to do with the amount of energy you've already imparted upon the string.

Comment: Language barrier I think!  'Depressing' is not the opposite of 'pressing'.

Comment: Yes, a language barrier indeed